# Magento 2: setdata() is not saving the values into the database

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.3, magento2.2

Controller file

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

{

    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $hello;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
                                \QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\HelloworldFactory $helloworld)
    {
        $this->hello = $helloworld;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld');
        $model->setData('post_id', $post['post_id']);
        $model->setData('title', $post['title']);
        $model->setData('content', $post['content']);
        $model->save();
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your values has beeen submitted successfully.'));
    }

}
```

Model file

QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld.php

```
<?php


namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model;



    class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel  
    {   
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld');
        }
    }
```

Resource Module:
QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld.php

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;


use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Helloworld extends AbstractDb

{

    protected function _construct()

    {

        $this->_init('sample_posts', 'post_id');

    }

}
```

Collection.php

QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld\Collection.php

```
<?php


namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;


class Collection extends AbstractCollection

{

    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->_init(
        'QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld',
        'QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld');

    }

}
```

Setup\InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {

    public function install( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable( 'sample_posts' )
        )->addColumn(
            'post_id',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            [ 'identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true ],
            'Post ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'title',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [ 'nullable' => false ],
            'Post Title'
        )->addColumn(
            'content',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            [ ],
            'Post Content'
        )->setComment(
            'Sample Post Table'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable( $table );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I can able to get the values from frontend phtml file using the method `getPostValue()`. But I can't able to save it. I like to save the values which I get from `getpostvalue()` method to the database. Please help me.

Answer (score 16):

Hi guys thanks for the support. Finally i found the solution after searching many sites.

In default Magento will try to update the database not insertion when we trying to save the data with the following code.

```
$_data = array('post_id'=>$data1,'title'=>$data2,'content'=>$data3);

$model->setData($_data);

$model->save();
```

Magento will check the Model to connect with the database. If the table has the **primarykey column**. And if we are trying to insert the value to the primary key field with the storefront value, Magento will look for **update it won't create new row(insertion)** in the table. At this time we need to use the **Magento features** in the Resource Model.

**protected $_isPkAutoIncrement = false;**

Then Magento will allow to store the value and create the new row in the table.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! Was wondering why the save method runs clean but no error

Comment: Great finding,... I was pulling my hair out on this one :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use the **objectmanager** follow this.

```
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $model = $this->hello->create();

    $data=array('title'=>$post['title'],'content'=>$post['content']);
    $id = $post['post_id']; //for updating the record
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }
    $model->setData($data);
    $model->save();
```

Here is complete [source](https://github.com/kingsatti/magento2_custommodel)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $data['post_id'] = $post['post_id'];
    $data['title'] = $post['title'];
    $data['content'] = $post['content'];*

$model = $this->_objectManager->create('QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld');

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }

            $model->setData($data);
    $model->save();
```

Use this code in `collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'post_id';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool
     */
    protected $metadataPool;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld',
        'QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld');
    }

}
```

Comment: i did like you said.. but still values are not saving in the database.

Comment: Check your model,  There is something wrong with it.

Comment: I have added my model in the post. please help me

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I have followed your code .. but this error as occurred when i di compile 
 QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld\Collection
  Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; File: 
/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/Model/ResourceModel/Helloworld/Collection.php

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: still values are not saving in the database. please update me if i did any mistake

Comment: now show setup/installSchema.php file

Comment: i have updated the post with installSchema. please check it'

Comment: now everything is fine It should work. Try to setup:upgrade and content-deploy and cache:flush. May be It will help

Comment: I did that but no use still values not saved in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69439/discussion-between-selva-kumar-and-ronak-chauhan).

Comment: May be you have done something wrong, I think you are new to Magento 2 so If you are leaning then I will provide you basic module.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $input = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
   $post = $this->_postFactory->create();

   if($input['post_id']){ // for update existing data
         $post->load($input['post_id']);
         $post->addData($input);
         $post->save();
   }else{ // insert new data
      $post->setData($input)->save();
   }
```